# Azure Alert Action connected to Logic App Webhook firing twice every time an alert is triggered

Tags: azure, triggers, alert, azure-logic-apps

I'm having this strange issue with Azure Monitor where an alert action that is pointing to a webhook is firing twice every time it gets triggered. (I'm assuming it isn't the alert that is firing twice necessarily but the Logic App that is receiving it that is firing twice for some reason)

**Action Alert Setup**

[image: Action Alert Setup]

**Action Timestamp**

[image: Action Timestamp]

**Related Logic App Sample Run History**

[image: Related Logic App Sample Run History]

**Basic Logic App Setup**

[image: Basic Logic App Setup]

Is this a common problem with hooking up action alerts to webhooks or logic apps or is there some setting I need to be aware of to prevent this?

Comment: Is there any solution on this? I have the same issue on app service, the alert action is triggered twice. First time it comes with alert message "fired", second time with message "resolved". I want that alert action would be triggered only once on "fired" status.

Comment: "fired" and "resolved" are also called monitorCondition

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **monitor condition** of your second alert message. Probably it is sending notification with monitor condition ***resolved***. For now it is not possible to disable triggering action group with ***resolved*** monitor condition but you can modify your webhook endpoint to ignore resolved state. Please check this issue: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/37167487-send-alerts-with-resolved-state-for-log-alert-rule